# D8. How can check is a formatter in use?

Tags: hooks, entities

I contribute a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dsbox) that provides additional formatters for the core image and link fields.

To protect the module from uninstall, I need a possibility to check if a providet formatter used on a image or link field.

To do this, I use the hook_system_info_alter() with

`$info['required'] = TRUE;
$info['explanation'] = t('Field formatter(s) in use');`

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

See the function dsbox_system_info_alter() of the [Drupal Swipebox module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dsbox) to get detailed informations of the solution.
Or, here is the link to the code of the module file: [dsbox.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/dsbox/tree/dsbox.module)